# Find all expressions of a prime as a sum of four squares

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to compute all solutions of
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = p
$$
where $x, y, z, w \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p \in \mathbb{P}$?

By efficient I mean linear on the number of solutions: $8(p + 1)$.

Comment: Have you seen algorithms for finding the solutions to Fermat's sum of two squares problem? Maybe there is some inspiration there.

Comment: Thank you, with that idea I managed to write an algorithm.

Comment: Great! Here's another reference I found http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1108/1108.6246.pdf. See the end for a little about algorithms for four squares.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similiar to langrage four square theorem.Michael O. Rabin and Jeffrey Shallit have found randomized polynomial-time algorithms for computing a representation $ n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2$ for a given integer n, in expected running time $O((logn)^2).$

Comment: Yes I know but I want to find all the solution.

Comment: @fran.aubry, here's an online calculator. It does the job, not the theory.

http://www.mathcelebrity.com/foursquare.php?num=97&pl=Show+Lagrange+Four-Square+Notation